# Docker: need help to get dockerized application work with SSL

Tags: java, apache, http, docker, ssl

Im facing a issue and hope its easier to solve than I can do it by myself.
Im a totally noob in docker and need to learn about it, and so I want to run a dockerized Web App on a vServer with SSL.
So far apache2 and docker work. The application has Port 8080 and with -p 80:8080 I get it running without problems.

I have installed letsencrypt and got my domain working with it. Everything fine. By opening the domain, the SSL certificate is activated and it shows me the apache "It works!" page. But now I dont know how to connect the docker application to the ssl. I have even killed apache rough with kill PID, and have set docker -p 443:8080, but it doesnt work. Well, I can open the IP/DOMAIN:443 but without SSL, and when I add https:// before, I get this error message in Chrome:

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

With [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) I get this error message:

```
http: error: SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')],)",) while doing GET request to URL:
```

I really hope that you can help me here. 
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear: where is the apache server? is it within Docker? outside docker and pointing to your content there? If you used let's encrypt, did you run it inside the container? when yo say 'it works' I can see the apache page, then what is it you're seeing? it is served from the docker container or not?

Comment: let's encrypt modifies your apache config, so if you didn't run it inside docker, it did't modify the apache config inside docker. if you did, but you somehow restarted recreated the container when you changed port mapping, you might just have wiped the changes made by lets encrypt.

Comment: @MrE I have the LAMP stack installed on Ubuntu 18.04. Apache is running as a own process, but if its working even without it, I can stop the service. Apache is outside of docker. Lets encrypt is outside of the docker. Only the Application (Sismics Docs) is running inside the docker container.

Comment: @MrE what is more recommended? Run apache outside or inside of docker? or is it better to run everything inside docker?

Comment: Apache is your server process. If it's not running inside the container, than what is the process running inside? I look at the docker file for sismics docs and there is no CMD or ENTRYPOINT, so it seems like it is only creating a volume for dependencies. You should run apache in another container and link that container as a volume to it, or expand the sismic image with your apache server, and run apache inside docker, exposing the right port. If apache is outside the container, the port mappign on docker are meaningless.

Comment: @MrE ah I see, so you mean it makes more sense running apache and letsencrypt inside of docker?

Comment: @MrE but how do I connect these images to work together?